# Passing multiple parameters into jQuery function

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am having trouble with passing multiple variables into on jQuery function (jQuery v3.6.1)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
function takeId(newButtonId, startTime, endTime, date, note){

    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    try {
        $('#bookingIdHidden').attr('value', newButtonId);
        $('#timeStart').attr('value', startTime);
        $('#timeEnd').attr('value', endTime);
        $('#date').attr('value', date);
        $('#note').attr('value', note);
    } catch(err) {
        alert(err); 
    }


};
```

For some reason this does not work (function does not run at all), however it does work when I only pass in one value and only set the value of #bookingIdHidden

This function is called using onclick() from a button, here:

```
<input type='button' name='edit' value='Edit' onclick="takeId($newButtonId, $startTime, $endTime, $date, $note);" id='1'>
```

Echo Version

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type='button' name='edit' value='Edit' onclick='takeId($newButtonId, $startTime, $endTime, $date, $note)' id='1'>" . "</td>";
```

```
<input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" onclick="takeId(1," 06:00:00.0000,="" 07:00:00.0000,="" 2023-01-05,="" ,="" 0)="" id="1">
```

Would anyone know why?

All help will be much appreciated

Comment: Note that you have newButtonId twice in the function definition, making it accept 6 arguments and passing 5. What gets assigned to newButtonId when you pass two arguments ... probably $startTime

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that! However, unfortunately the result is the same

Comment: Also, in your onclick event, the input button is not closed properly. It should be `<input type='button' name='edit' value='Edit' onclick="takeId($newButtonId, $startTime, $endTime, $date, $note);" id='1'>`

Comment: Do you actually intend to set the value attribute rather than the value property? it's not usually useful to do so, unless you actually wanted to update the default value.

Comment: You are opening and ```input``` and you are closing a ```button``` and you didn't put the function inside quotes.

Comment: Jquery 5.2.3? did you mean 3.2.3? or am i really that far out of the loop on jquery

Comment: I do intend to set the value of the input, it will act as a placeholder but if the user decides not to change it the original value can still be passed to the backend.

I have updated my input to Tivi's suggestion, unfortunately it is still not working

Comment: How are `$newButtonId` etc all defined?  Are they really JS variables, or are you trying to use PHP variables there?  First step of debugging would be to check your variables, are they all what you expect?  Are you perhaps forgetting to `<?php echo $newButtonId; ?>`, etc? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: Hi, Don't Panic. They are php variables, they are taken from the result of an sql query, these variables are then put into a table using a while loop along with the buttons on the side. My method works completely fine for just the php var being inputted into the jQuery function, however, not so fine with more

Comment: Do you `echo` that button in PHP? Is that javascript code inside a `.php` file? Are there any "special" characters in your PHP variables? Have you tried using quotes? `onclick="takeId('$newButtonId', '$startTime', '$endTime', '$date', '$note')`?

Comment: Yes, I do echo the button inside a .php file and I shall give the quotes a try right now, thanks. Update: No luck

Comment: Can you post the `echo` you use to print out that button? There's `"` and `'` quotes inside that "string", one of those should be escaped. Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: There we go, have done

Comment: The code you have shown does not echo anything.  Please edit your question,show us your real code.  Have you checked the actual rendered output in the browser source?

Comment: The rendered output is fine, would you like a screenshot? More than happy to provide one. I can also provide the code for the whole table, if you would like

Comment: I mean the HTML - if you're going to share it pls do it as text, like the rest of your code.  [Here's a simplified version of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/p97z3rg1/) which works fine.

Comment: It looks like your variables are not quoted? If they are strings they need to be.

Comment: Which section of HTML would you like, table or modal or both? While your code does indeed work in jsFiddle, it doesn't for me inside the php echo statement (off course with " changed to ')

Comment: Only the code we're looking at ... ? `<input type='button' name='edit' ...` The first one if it is in a loop, assuming the first one does not work?

Comment: Ok cool, I have added the code as it stands currently, to the bottom of my question for you

Comment: We need to see the **HTML** of a single button that is not working, the first one if none of them work.  The rendered HTML that your browser gets.  Not the PHP.  If you use your browser's devtools, or view source, you will see what HTML that PHP generates.  That is what the browser and Javascript are processing, and that is the part that is not working.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand what you mean. Will add it now

Comment: I am not sure where the =, is coming from. I echoed the var $startTime and there were no =,

Comment: You can see the qoutes and code is all messed up in the code you've added.  I updated [my JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/p97z3rg1/) to show your code isn't working - open your browser devtools and check the console, you will see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at (index):33:144)`.

Comment: The error I am receiving is SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}' and it points the line which contains echo "<table id='adminTable'>";

Comment: It is working now! It needed ` around the variable names and ' around the function call after onclick. Your help has been very much appreciated

Comment: Use your browser devtools when developing, you will see the errors caused by syntax errors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools

Comment: I shall make sure to do that, it has been very helpful. Once again, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are passing extra parameter while calling a function. Remove extra parameters and try. If it is still not work then try below solution

Pass parameters to function in single quotes like given below code snippet.

```
<input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" onclick="takeId(1, '06:00:00.0000', '07:00:00.0000', '2023-01-05', '') id="1">
```